# Set value relation widget to change available options depending on input to another field

Tags: qgis, geopackage, database

I'm building a Geopackage database, with several tables with no geometry that function primarily as field data collection forms to use through QField.

As part of this database, there are two tables containing general, non-spatial data: one with a list of Job Codes, and one with a list of staff.

The Job_Codes table only stores fid and Job_Code.

When adding a new staff member to the Field_Staff table, I'm storing full_name, initials (using an expression), and then Job_Codes_Staff using the *Value Relation* widget to allow selection of multiple job codes from Job_Code in the previous table, to reflect all jobs that individual has ever worked on. Since it's a value relation, they're stored in the format (x,y,z).

I then have a third table, Project_Unit. In this table, I need to record the job code (in Job_Code_Unit) of the project on which the unit was completed, and the Initials of staff who worked on that unit. I want to have a *Value Map* widget for Job_Code, and a *Value Relation* widget for staff with a drop down list showing the names only of people who are associated with that Job_Code.

So if Field_Staff has

> | Alice Cooper | AS | (ProjX,ProjY,ProjZ)

> | James Dean   | JD | (ProjX)

> | David Bowie  | DB | (ProjX,ProjZ)

and in Field_Staff I select ProjY, I only want it to be possible to select Alice Cooper (AS) as the staff.

N.B. since the jobs are stored as a single string in the Field_Staff table, any expression has to search that string for the selected job.

I tried using `"Job_Codes_Staff" ILIKE '%' || attribute("Job_Code_Unit") || '%'` but that returned no staff when a job code was selected.

Stuck and unsure what to do now. Is my expression wrong? Do I need to set up a relation in project properties? How do I do that to achieve the desired result if so?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se. A cleaner approach would be to add all the projects to another table (just fid + project code for now), and then have a mapping table that has an association from user to project, where each project and user can appear multiple times.

Comment: Thanks - the more I tried to push it through the more I spotted flaws. I've gone back to DB fundamentals now and I'm redesigning the whole architecture properly with good joins and mapping tables.